# Solving commutator equation: $AX-XA=M$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the field square matrices $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ or $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. I wish to solve the equation $AX-XA=M$ for a given $A,M$.

Obviously this is just $n^2$ linear equations and thus is trivial to actually calculate as $M_{ij}=\sum_k(A_{ik}X_{kj}-A_{kj}X_{ik})$, but I wonder if there is some closed-form equation for $X_{ij}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This equation is solved in: F. Gantmacher, Matrix theory, chapter VIII, §3.

Comment: You mean §2,§3; it basically say the equation is either contradictory (have no solutions) or have infinite number of solutions $X=X_0+X_1$ where $X_0$ is a particular solution and $X_1$ is a matrix which commute with A, and thus solves the homogeneous equation $AX=XA$.

Comment: Yes, but I think it is hardly possible to say something more about solving this equation. Of course, it is §3 instead of §4, sorry.

Comment: Could you please describe the answer here? The reference is a bit hard to track. Could you add some keywords? Chapter names?